# PixelFormat for 16 bit images

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixelformat

[PixelFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

> `Format16bppArgb1555` 
>   The pixel format is 16 bits per pixel. The color information specifies 32,768 shades of color, of which 5 bits are red, 5 bits are green, 5 bits are blue, and 1 bit is alpha.
>
> `Format16bppGrayScale` 
>   The pixel format is 16 bits per pixel. The color information specifies 65536 shades of gray.
>
> `Format16bppRgb555`
>   Specifies that the format is 16 bits per pixel; 5 bits each are used for the red, green, and blue components. The remaining bit is not used.
>
> `Format16bppRgb565`
>   Specifies that the format is 16 bits per pixel; 5 bits are used for the red component, 6 bits are used for the green component, and 5 bits are used for the blue component.

I never found any 16-bit image on the Internet.

When are these pixel formats used?

Comment: 16-bit format is old. It is about 2/3 the size of 24-bit bitmap, but it looses a lot of color information. It supports about 60,000 colors, as opposed to 24-bit bitmap which supports 16 million colors. There are better options for compression these days, like *.png, so 16-bit bitmap is rarely used anymore. Still some devices may use 16-bit bitmap.

Comment: As an addition to what Barmak said: 16 bit color formats were called High Color, and 24 bit was called TrueColor. They were mainly used because while they still did not achieve the same color range as True Color (65536 vs 16777216 colors) it still looked quite similar, but was vastly better looking than 8 bit color modes with just 256 colors. The question why you would use 16 bit instead of 24 bit is basically memory: an 640x480x24 bit image requires almost 1MB whereas 640x480x16 bit only required 600kB which was a huge help on 4MB RAM machines like I had at that time in the 90s.

Comment: Also: They tend to be __not supported__ in GDI+ even though the still are in the enumeration. The 16bpp color  formats are useless anyway but the 16bpp grayscale would be really important even without a monitor that can display it..

Comment: @TaW As far as I know 16 bit colour is perfectly supported in GDI+... it's just 16-bit grayscale that isn't. I've used 16-bit colours a lot when working with files from old games.

Comment: @Nyerguds: OK, noted.